# How can I pass something string-like with the `Read` trait to an implementation of `From`?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm writing a tokenizer, and for convenience I wrote a `Reader` object, that returns words one at a time. When `words` is exhausted, it reads from the `BufReader` to populate the `words`. Accordingly, I figured that `file` and `words` should both live in the struct.

The problem I'm having is that I want to test it by passing in strings to be tokenized, rather than having to rely on files. That's why I tried to implement `From` on both a `File` and then `&str` and `String`. The latter two don't work (as highlighted below).

I tried to annotate `Reader` with a lifetime, that I then used in the implementation of `From<&'a str>`, but that didn't work. I ended up with a `Reader<'a, T: Read>`, but the compiler complained that nothing used the lifetime parameter.

An alternative implementation of `From<&'static str>` works fine, but that means any strings passed in have to exist for the static lifetime.

I also saw this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574458/how-can-i-explicitly-specify-a-lifetime-when-implementing-a-trait), but it seems to be different since their `Enum` has a lifetime parameter.

I have two supplementary question along with my overall question in the title:

1. I also saw `FromStr`, but haven't tried to use that yet - is it appropriate for this?
2. Are my code comments re variable ownership/lifetimes below correct?

My minimal example is here (with imports elided):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Reader<T: Read> {
    file: BufReader<T>,
    words: Vec<String>,
}

impl From<File> for Reader<File> {
    fn from(value: File) -> Self {                     // value moves into from
        Reader::new(BufReader::new(value))             // value moves into BufReader(?)
    }
}

// THE NEXT TWO DON'T WORK
impl From<&str> for Reader<&[u8]> {
    fn from(value: &str) -> Self {                     // Compiler can't know how long the underlying data lives
        Reader::new(BufReader::new(value.as_bytes()))  // The data may not live as long as BufReader
    }
}

impl From<String> for Reader<&[u8]> {
    fn from(value: String) -> Self {                   // value moves into from
        Reader::new(BufReader::new(value.as_bytes()))  // value doesn't move into BufReader or Reader
    }                                                  // value gets dropped
}


impl<T: Read> Reader<T> {
    fn new(input: BufReader<T>) -> Self {
        Self {
            file: input,
            words: vec![],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `&str` one compiles when I add lifetime annotations: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1dfe78a801ffe7ade0e2bc97faea3937). Is that what you were looking for? (It doesn't work for `String` because the function's signature moves the string into the parameter, and cannot return bytes that belong to a local variable destroyed at the return from the function. `&String` would likely work, but then you can as well use `&str`.)

Comment: Yes, that does work, thanks! The thing I was missing when I was adding lifetime annotations was annotating the bytes (i.e. `Reader<&'a [u8]>`). If you want to post it as an answer, I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&str` one compiles with lifetime annotations ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ac8d461c2062cf627fb62c02d8291e61)):

```
impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Reader<&'a [u8]> {
    fn from(value: &'a str) -> Self {
        Reader::new(BufReader::new(value.as_bytes()))
    }
}
```

As discussed in the comments, you need to only annotate the reference, not try to incorporate lifetime annotations into the `Reader` itself.

Note that the same approach doesn't work for `String` because the signature of `from` moves it into the function, and the function cannot return bytes that belong to a local variable. You could implement it for `&String`, but then you can as well use `&str`.

Comment: FWIW, the version without lifetimes doesn't work because it is desugared as `impl<'a, 'b> From<&'a str> for Reader<&'b [u8]>`; i.e., it claims to turn any `&str` into a `Reader` of any lifetime, which is obviously not true.